# I cannot restore backup file .bak to another server (SQL Server 2017 )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I try to backup and test restore the database on the different servers but I got the error below
I already using DBCC CHECKDB and there is no error found.
Please help guide me on how to fix this issue.

MS SQL Server Version: MS SQL Server 2017 Cumulative Patch 27
Recover Type: Full
Database Mode: Simple

> Restore of database 'New_DB' failed.
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a Hotfix from Technical Support. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: WIN-OSJVISIE08A
> Error Number: 3624
> Severity: 17
> State: 1
> Line Number: 1

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server error log for details? Add that error message to your question.

Comment: I saw only the log that I post.
Is there any log I should check and where?

Comment: DBCC Check result seems to be no error. I still got the error when try to restore the backup.

CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: You can view the SQL Server error log from SSMS Object Explorer under Mangement-->SQL Server Logs-->Current

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server where you are getting the backup from - and the version of SQL Server where you are trying to restore?  It appears you may be trying to restore to a lower version - which isn't supported.

Comment: Here is the Latest Log.
Date,Source,Severity,Message
11/06/2021 00:00:03,spid40s,Unknown,This instance of SQL Server has been using a process ID of 2784 since 11/5/2021 8:08:21 PM (local) 11/5/2021 1:08:21 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
11/05/2021 23:10:14,spid57,Unknown,[INFO] HkHostFreezeCkptTrimming(). Database ID: [5]. HkTrimLSN Frozen: [0]

Comment: Cont.
11/05/2021 23:10:14,spid57,Unknown,A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically<c/> an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption<c/> consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup<c/> a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a Hotfix from Technical Support.

Comment: Cont.
11/05/2021 23:10:14,spid57,Unknown,Error: 3624<c/> Severity: 17<c/> State: 1.
11/05/2021 23:10:14,spid57,Unknown,SQL Server Assertion: File: <recoveryunit.cpp><c/> line=8471 Failed Assertion = '!!(pDbInfo->dbi_hkRecoveryLSN == LSN (0<c/> 0<c/> 0)) == !!(pDbInfo->dbi_hkLogTruncationLSN == LSN (0<c/> 0<c/> 0))'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement<c/> use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity<c/> or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.

Comment: Can I attach the error log file to the post?

There is a lot more log that I cannot understand.

Comment: Both are MS SQL Server 2017 CU27 sir.

Comment: Here is the latest error I found.
11/08/2021 11:26:24,Windows Error Reporting,Information,Fault bucket <c/> type 0<nl/>Event Name: SQLException64<nl/>Response: Not available<nl/>Cab Id: 0<nl/><nl/>Problem signature:<nl/>P1: sqlservr.exe<nl/>P2: 0.0.0.0<nl/>P3: 0000000000000000<nl/>P4: sqllang.dll<nl/>P5: 2017.140.3421.10<nl/>P6: 00000000616809D9<nl/>P7: 17068<nl/>P8: 0000000000397B4D<nl/>P9: 00000000C0EAF7C5<nl/>P10: <nl/><nl/>Attached files:<nl/>\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL

Comment: Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0002.mdmp<nl/>\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0002.txt<nl/>\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0002.log<nl/><nl/>These files may be available here:<nl/><nl/><nl/>Analysis symbol: <nl/>Rechecking for solution: 0<nl/>Report Id: 07a30548-404c-11ec-960d-000c29d8fc70<nl/>Report Status: 262144<nl/>Hashed bucket:,(0),1001,,WIN-EFU4JUHKEF0

Comment: 11/08/2021 11:26:24,MSSQLSERVER,Error,SQL Server Assertion: File: <recoveryunit.cpp><c/> line=8532 Failed Assertion = '!!(pDbInfo->dbi_hkRecoveryLSN == LSN (0<c/> 0<c/> 0)) == !!(pDbInfo->dbi_hkLogTruncationLSN == LSN (0<c/> 0<c/> 0))'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement<c/> use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity<c/> or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.,(2),17066,,WIN-EFU4JUHKEF0

Any body please help

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products that are listed in the "Applies to" section. [Click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4527538-fix-a-system-assertion-check-has-failed-error-when-a-procedure-call-is-made-from-clr-with-an-output-large-object-argument-fc3a9912-f54d-e0a8-ed12-9537bcd9b68c#:%7E:text=Typically%2C%20an%20assertion%20failure%20is,will%20be%20sent%20to%20Microsoft.) to check official update by Microsoft

This issue is fixed in the following cumulative updates for SQL Server:

1. [Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4527376-cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2019-a8dae09e-96b5-9f13-9092-977341fafe17)
2. [Cumulative Update 18 for SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4527377-cumulative-update-18-for-sql-server-2017-9b3a313d-054a-c6b7-200e-1744dfce48f3)

As a solution, you can upgrade your current MS SQL Server(where you are getting the backup from) & than you can switch to the another server.

Thanks :)